# Raspbian Lite not connecing to internet

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I'm running Raspbian Jessie Lite (tty only) and attempting to connect to the internet using `wpa_supplicant`. The error I receive is `WRONG_KEY` and `4-Way Handshake failed`, however, I know my passphrase is correct. The command I am running is

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211
```

`sudo iwconfig` **does** show `wlan0`. Additionally, my configuration file (`/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`) consists of:

```
network={
    ssid="Hauk"
    psk="passphrase"
    proto=WPA2
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Again, my passphrase *is* correct. I have tried many solutions which have worked for other people, including setting `proto=WPA RSN` and trying other drivers like `wext`

Comment: Does the `passphrase` is generated by `wpa_passphrase` ?

Comment: @GAD3R no, it is the plain passphrase.

Comment: Run `wpa_passphrase yourSSID yourPASSWD` form the terminal, copy and past the `psk` on your configuration file then try to connect